# Creating a customizable high pressure extensions line for cga 580

Tags: design

So I'm trying to set up a keg on nitro. The way my room is laid out, id like to have the n2 cylinder far away from the regulator and keg. One side of this setup requires cga580 male, the other side requires cga 580 female.

Because of the specifics of this setup I need the line to be a high pressure line that can connect directly to the cylinder.

So my goal is to essentially make an extension cable that I can place different cga 580 ends on. I've seen this referred to as a pigtail.

I can't figure out which parts will fit which other parts though. I bought this expensive cga580 male to male pigtail thinking I could remove one of the male heads but I can't remove the head.

Does anyone know if getting a stainless pigtail with 1/4 npt female ends would allow me to add adapters that are 1/4 npt to cga 580?

If so could someone point me towards the adapters that will allow this setup?

Or if not, does anyone know og anywhere that sells a cga 580 male to female pigtail?

Or any other ideas?

Comment: I would only consider doing an extension AFTER the regulator.

Comment: @SolarMike could you give me some context on why? It would be much better for my setup to do it before the reg. Is there some reason why this would be dangerous? I would be using a stainless pigtail and machined adapters, all of it rated to way over cylinder pressure.


But I definitely want to understand if I'm getting myself into a dangerous situation